# how can i bind alloy data to tableview

Tags: titanium-alloy

Please guide me i am unable to bind the data

my data object is like this

```
    data = [
    {
    "title":"this is title one",
    "namespace":"this is namespaceone"
    },
    {
    "title":"this is title two",
    "namespace":"this is namespacetwo"
    }
]
```

and my myxml.xml is as follows

```
<Collection src="data"></Collection>
    <Window id="homeWin" title="HOME">

        <TableView dataCollection="data" top='50'>
            <TableViewRow>{title}</TableViewRow>
        </TableView>    
    </Window>
```

but it not bind the data.
where I missed. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Either just give the `TableView` an `id` attribute and do `$.<id>.data = data;` or follow the data binding guide to use collections:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding